# How does an IntBuffer compare to an array in terms of memory usage?

Tags: java

So I have a big list of integers I have to work with (in the order of 70Mb). As a part of the process of reading them, I need to temporarily store them. I can either spread them over several IntBuffers, or allocate a couple of large arrays.

I couldn't find any documentation however on how an IntBuffer compares to an array in terms of memory usage (with all the metadata that java adds). Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Why do you need them, and is there further knowledge about these ints? Are they a set, or is there repetition? Does the order play a role or not?

Comment: @userunknown To be precise, it is geometry data from an OBJ file. While parsing the file, vertices need to be linked to indices in order to determine to which triangle they belong in the 3D model. I'm still trying to figure out a good algorithm to accomplish this, but since my attempt with ArrayLists failed disastrously (over 500Mb in memory usage), I was wondering about more memory efficient storage methods.

Comment: What does IntBuffer give you that arrays don't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is very little difference between a `int[]` and a heap `IntBuffer` or a direct `IntBuffer` in terms of memory usage esp if the arrays are large. (There is a small over head)

In terms of performance `int[]` is the fastest and a direct `IntBuffer` with native byte ordering is the second fastest.  The advantage of the IntBuffer is that its off heap and you can have much larger sizes e.g. 70 GB without increasing the heap size or the Full GC times.

For a 70 MB array, it small enough that the simplest solution `int[]` is likely to be the best. (It will also be the easiest to write and most efficient to run)

Comment: So do either of them store metadata per element, or is it a small amount of metadata for the whole object, after which it just stores data?

Comment: Both store some meta data per object, not per element. In the case of int[] its 8-12 bytes. For IntBuffer its approx 40 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Relative to 70MB of ints, the metadata an IntBuffer adds is nothing. But a profiler will give you a more complete answer.